# Print Contribution Receipt Offline

Tags: contributions, receipts, printing

Some donor wants a receipt of their contribution printed. I could not find any option other than printer icon on the top right. But that gives a very barebone format. What is the best way to go about it, please? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can make pdf and then print it.

1. Go to **CiviCRM Menu** -> **Contribution** -> **Find contribution**
2. Click on search button.
3. Select any contributions which you need
4. On the top of table is located **"actions"** dropdown. Chose **"Receipts - print or email"**.
5. Then You will redirected on **"Print Contribution Receipts"** page. Click on **"PDF Receipts"** select pdf template. And then click on **"Process receipt"**. After that it generates pdf.

If you don't have any pdf template, you can create in **"[your domain name]/index.php?q=civicrm/admin/pdfFormats&reset=1"** page. Be caerful, don't set big value for margin param(try to set "1").